# WordPress plugin for shipping calculation

Tags: php, validation, wordpress, e-commerce, integration-testing

I am writing a WordPress plugin that allows shipping calculation on the product page. Originally, shipping calculation is only available in the cart.

To calculate shipping costs on product page, three things are necessary: A product with valid dimensions, the quantity and the destination postcode.

Here's what it does before getting to the `getCostPerShippingMethod()` method bellow:

- Receives a REST request
- Sanitizes and validates it
- Generate the Payload object (which extracts product dimensions, etc)
- Determines Shipping Zone and Shipping Methods (Example: We offer UPS for postcode X and also Local Pickup for postcode Y)
- Passes an array of Shipping Methods to `getCostPerShippingMethod()` bellow.

Then, at `getCostPerShippingMethod()`:

- Create a Package object for it, which calculates cubage according to product dimensions, quantity and shipping method rules (each shipping method may calculate cubage differently)
- Instantiate a Handler for this shipping method, which is a internal class prepared to handle the external shipping method calculation rules
- Handler validates the package dimensions per shipping method. (Example: Local pickup: no limit | UPS: max 30kg, 200cm height, etc)
- Then it calls the Handler's calculate method, which does it's magic depending on the Shipping Method and payload requested and return the shipping costs

The array returned by `getCostPerShippingMethod()` is then cascaded down to the frontend to be displayed to the user.

```
/**
 * Calculates shipping costs for an array of shipping methods
 *
 * @param array $shipping_methods
 * @param Payload $payload
 * @return array
 */
public static function getCostPerShippingMethod(array $shipping_methods, Payload $payload)
{
    $instance = new self;
    $shipping_costs = array();

    foreach ($shipping_methods as $shipping_method) {
        $shipping_method_slug = sanitize_title(get_class($shipping_method));
        $response = new Response($shipping_method);

        try {
            // Create Package based on product and quantities per Shipping Method
            $package = Package::makeFrom($payload->getProduct(), $payload->getQuantity(), $shipping_method);
            $payload->setPackage($package);

            // Create CFPP handler for this Shipping Method
            $cfpp_handler = Factory::createHandler($shipping_method);

            // Gives a chance to set rules, then validate Payload per Shipping Method
            $cfpp_handler->beforeValidate()->validate($payload);

            // Calculate Costs
            do_action('cfpp_before_calculate_cost', $payload, $shipping_method);
            $shipping_costs[] = apply_filters('cfpp_response_success_' . $shipping_method_slug, $cfpp_handler->calculate($payload));

        } catch(PackageException $e) {
            do_action('cfpp_response_package_exception', $shipping_method_slug);
            $shipping_costs[] = $response->error($e->getMessage());
        } catch (FactoryException $e) {
            do_action('cfpp_response_factory_exception', $shipping_method_slug);
            $shipping_costs[] = $response->error($e->getMessage());
        } catch (ValidationErrorException $e) {
            do_action('cfpp_response_validation_exception', $shipping_method_slug);
            $shipping_costs[] = $response->error($e->getMessage());
        } catch (HandlerException $e) {
            do_action('cfpp_response_handler_exception', $shipping_method_slug);
            $shipping_costs[] = $response->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Successes first, errors last
    $shipping_costs = $instance->orderShippingCosts($shipping_costs);

    return $shipping_costs;
}
```

It all works fine. However, I'm having problems testing this class. I can't see how, but this method probably has poor architecture.

How can I improve this code to make it more testable and architecturally correct?